# Is there a way to create external link in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, versioning, external

I'm trying to include an older version of some lib into a new project. Is there a way to notify the current repository that I only need specific revision of other library, and not the tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of Mercurial there is the concept of [sub-repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos) or subrepos, and there is an .hgsubstate file in the base directory of a project that records which version of each subrepo is the one that's being used.  That should solve your problem if the other library is maintained in a Mercurial repository.

Comment: If you're using crew it can even be in subversion.